# Is there a way to get sections from an IOFactory?

Tags: php, laravel, phpword, phpoffice

I'm using PHPWord to use a template but when I save my file in HTML format I only see its body and not the header or footer. So I would like to get these sections to insert them in the HTML part

```
  $Content = IOFactory::load($saveDocPath); 
  $Writer = IOFactory::createWriter($Content,'HTML');       
  $Writer->save($savePath);
```

if I use dd() I can see the header and footer of the docx file

```
#phpWord: PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord {#1299 ▼
    -sections: array:1 [▼
      0 => PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\Section {#1493 ▼
        #container: "Section"
        -style: PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Section {#1494 ▶}
        -headers: array:1 [▶]
        -footers: array:1 [▶]
        -footnoteProperties: null
        #elements: array:25 [▶]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. A quote from one of the contributors:

> Header & Footer are only applicable when printing pages, which is not the case for HTML.

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/1105#issuecomment-317132143